# Fastest algorithm for finding a word on a word search grid

Tags: algorithm

I was interviewed for a software developer position. It was a phone interview. Was asked this and it has been bugging me all day

The interviewer asked me to come up with a general approach for finding a word on a word search grid. For simplicity, there is no need to worry about memory constraints or searching diagonally on the grid (just left to right and top to bottom).

The best I could come up with was to create a hash map on startup of the grid program (before calling the word search every time) ... have it create a hash map of **character** => **row,col indices**. That way you could perform the initial scan in O(1) time. And then from there basically scan left to right or top to bottom.

I got the impression from him that there was a better solution and that I wasn't there yet. What is the fastest algorithm for solving such a problem?

Comment: Are we counting precomputation time when we say "fastest"? If not, then we can just precompute everything, and all queries will be O(1).

Comment: If your question is "please mind-read what the interviewer wanted" I'm afraid this is not possible.  If you want to know what they meant, then perhaps follow up with the person asking the question.  There are a tremendous spectrum of solutions to this and picking the "best" requires more details than given here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If memory isn't an issue and I can preprocess the data, then I would:

1. Make a string representation of the grid in row-major order. This is for searching horizontally.
2. Make a string representation of the grid in column-major order, for searching vertically.

When given a word to search for, I would use a standard search algorithm (KMP, Boyer-Moore, etc.) to:

1. Search for the word in the row-major string.
2. Reverse the word and search in the row-major string.
3. Search for the word in the column-major string.
4. Reverse the word and search in the column-major string.

That gives a good balance between simplicity, memory usage, and speed. In fact, it's dead simple because you wouldn't really need to implement the search algorithm. Just use whatever is provided by the runtime library.

Of course, you could easily modify the standard search algorithm to treat the two-dimensional grid as a one-dimensional string without actually doing the transformation ahead of time. That's more complicated and would be slightly slower in searching than preprocessing, but it would require less memory.

Doing it in place with a single scan gets complicated. But you could do the horizontal searches (i.e. left-to-right and right-to-left) easily enough in a single scan. And the vertical searches in a single scan. You'd just be searching for two different strings in a single pass: the word, and a reversed version of the word.

Comment: This is a **horrible** method. The time to find each word is O(4n), where n is the number of characters in the puzzle. If you add diagonals, your algorithm balloons to O(8n). Both of those estimations ignore the fact that your algorithm will find words not in the puzzle.. For those looking for a fast solution, just know this problem can be solved in O(n * m) time where n is the number of times the first character appears and m is the number of times the last character appears for all words having 2 or more characters. All single letter words can be found in O(1) time.

Comment: @deAtog: I stated up front that this isn't the absolute fastest way to do it, but it is linear. Your O(n*m) could be much worse than O(4n). Depending on the size of the grid and how many searches you're going to do, implementing a modified Aho-Corasick trie and search would likely outperform either of our stated methods. Also, you'll have to explain how my method could result in finding words that aren't there.

Comment: Since you are joining columns/rows, your method would find words that  wrap from one column/row to the next. Additional work would be needed to ensure that the word found doesn't cross a row/column boundary. My method would never be worse than your method, because only a fraction of the n * m combinations need to be evaluated, the vast majority can be skipped. Of those that do only a single direction needs to be considered and the word either matches or it doesn't.

Comment: I think I've given quite a few hints as to how to implement this. If you can find single letter words in O(1), the first characters of the word in O(m), and the last characters of the word in O(n) then the only mildly difficult issue is how to determine if the letters from the first character to the last are correct, of which there are m*n combinations to evaluate. The majority of the combinations will be invalid and can be proved invalid in O(1) time. The others can be proved valid or invalid in at most O(w) time, where w is the length of the word.

Comment: @deAtog, In your O(n*m) solution, m is likely to be larger than 4, so it's actually slower than just searching the 4 directions once you've found the first letter.

Comment: Surprisingly, it's not. While m is likely to be larger than 4 (or 8 if including diagonals) many of the combinations can be proved invalid in O(1). Looking only at the 4 or 8 characters around the first character may lead you down many invalid paths. These paths take at most O(w) time to consider, where w is the length of the word. In the worst case scenario, you approach O(4*n*w) or O(8*n*w). Even if we assume most paths from the first character are invalid in O(w/2) time, then m would need to be larger than (4 or 8) * (w / 2) for a given word for a directional search to be faster.

Answer (score 1):

If preprocessing the data doesn't count towards the time then you can prepare an array of vectors that contains the positions of each letter.  So given the first letter, you go right to the location(s) where it occurs, then check the 4 (or 8) directions for the rest of the letters.

In the comments to another answer, @deAtog seems to suggest using the array to find the positions of the first *and last* letter.  But for even a medium sized grid, there are likely to be more than 4 occurrences of each letter, so it will probably be faster to just check the 4 directions.

You can extend the array idea to an array of digrams (2 letter combinations). The digram map contains position and direction of the digrams  Now given the first 2 letters of a word, you go right to the location and direction of those letters. For single-letter words, you just check all digrams that start with the letter. I think this provides a good combination of size and speed.

If you really don't care about space, you could extent the array idea all the way to creating a concordance of the positions and directions of, say, the most popular 50,000 words.  Now if you're given a word that's in that list, you can find it in the time required to locate the word in the concordance.

But I think the concordance is overkill. Mapping digrams to position/direction is probably a good compromise for speed and space.

Finally, if preprocessing *does* matter and you're looking for just one word, then you can apply a trick to the brute force method: store the grid with extra spaces around the border. These contain a non-letter. Doing this means you never have to check the array bounds. If you run off the edge of the grid, the value there won't match any letter in a word so you'll stop check right there.

Comment: You were correct up until the middle of the second paragraph to your answer. I also stated that you can invalidate many of the combinations between the two lists in O(1) time. Once you've determined the O(1) algorithm here, the performance approaches to O(n*m) time to find a word.

Answer (score -1):

I would say that he wanted you to push for clarification. If you are searching for **words**, then I agree with your approach. If you're searching for a single word then a linear search for the first letter followed by a search in each direction for the rest of the word would be quicker.

Comment: This isn't much better than Jim's method. The advantages to this approach is that you're not duplicating the puzzle in a manner that would allow you to find words not in the puzzle, and the first character of the word is found in O(n) time rather than O(4n) time, or O(8n) time if you include diagonals. If I were the interviewer, I'd consider both of these answers as something an average developer would come up with, with your solution being only marginally better than Jim's.